# Silent Hill 1 audio issues on emulator

Tags: emulation, silent-hill

A couple of years ago I got Silent Hill 1 for PS1, and I played it on my laptop thanks to the ePSXe emulator. I found something weird about the game: in the dialogue sequences there was no speech, I got the subtitles and the background audio but not a simple word from the characters. I believed it was a configuration problem but I played Resident Evil 3 and Dino Crisis 1 recently, with the same emulator settings, and I got the dialogs voices. So, is this a problem related with the silent Hill I have or there are no voices in the dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may perhaps be an audio issue with the ROM file you are using, which you can't do anything about. From my personal experience, I have played Silent Hill 1 on my PC using ePSXe also and experienced similar issues as well.

I remedied this by forcing the audio codec to a different option than what was selected as default.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Done, despite I changed the audio settings I still have no voices in the dialogs. Is like you said before, the ROM file has some issues.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help :(. Sometimes it works but yes, in this instance their is most likely an issue with that particular ROM.